# Java: what does the identifier do in the catch sentence?

Tags: java, try-catch, identifier

I am a newbie in programming. I was learning java and I found the try/catch. I understood the and the concept very well but I have a question  with the catch sentence: What does the identifier do in the catch sentence?, How does it work? How do I use it?

If you do not understand:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {

            Integer.parseInt("m");

        }catch (Exception e) {System.out.println("ERROR");} //This identifier (e)

    }

}
```

Probably the answer is very obvious but i want be sure.

Comment: The identifier `e` represents an `Exception` instance of which was *caught*. This instance contains useful properties for debugging purposes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can be trivially answered by reading the official Java tutorials. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` is the exception you should be examining or at least printing so that you know what error occurred, where and possibly why. add

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score -1):

The catch catches Exception e. This means that the exception returns an Exception object with the identifier e. 
This is assigned by the user and you could do catch
    (Exception caughtException).
Exceptions have methods and can be used in the catch block. For example 
    System.out.println(e) 
will print the details of the Exception method.